# Kubectl is not able to get cluster info from minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new to Kubernetes and trying out the minikube tutorial. I have a Mac and I have installed minikube, kubectl cli and hyperkit driver. Docker daemon has been running. I have started minikube by passing the proxy variables.

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit \
               --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://my-http-proxy-host:my-http-proxy-port \
               --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://my-https-proxy-host:my-https-proxy-port
```

I set kubectl to use minikube context.

However when I run the:

> kubectl cluster-info

I am getting the below error:

> Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Below is the output of `minikube logs | grep error`:

```
Oct 21 16:53:22 minikube localkube[3010]: E1021 16:53:22.531735    3010 proxier.go:1701] Failed to delete stale service IP 10.96.0.10 connections, error: error deleting connection tracking state for UDP service IP: 10.96.0.10, error: error looking for path of conntrack: exec: "conntrack": executable file not found in $PATH
Oct 21 16:53:26 minikube localkube[3010]: E1021 16:53:26.781082    3010 proxier.go:964] Failed to delete kube-system/kube-dns:dns endpoint connections, error: error deleting conntrack entries for UDP peer {10.96.0.10, 172.17.0.3}, error: error looking for path of conntrack: exec: "conntrack": executable file not found in $PATH
Oct 21 16:53:37 minikube localkube[3010]: E1021 16:53:37.528164    3010 proxier.go:1701] Failed to delete stale service IP 10.96.0.10 connections, error: error deleting connection tracking state for UDP service IP: 10.96.0.10, error: error looking for path of conntrack: exec: "conntrack": executable file not found in $PATH
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.513057    3010 remote_runtime.go:115] StopPodSandbox "9aad7169cf8c357f512575118efdcb88fb796bcc7642c44b5f3b79f2310720ff" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.513654    3010 remote_runtime.go:115] StopPodSandbox "172f08e151ec2a7b12132bb65917b7d993cbba9978f4ff5d6f272fba132317d0" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox "172f08e151ec2a7b12132bb65917b7d993cbba9978f4ff5d6f272fba132317d0": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.513758    3010 kuberuntime_manager.go:595] killPodWithSyncResult failed: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "22d0437c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox \"172f08e151ec2a7b12132bb65917b7d993cbba9978f4ff5d6f272fba132317d0\": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]"
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.513805    3010 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod 22d0437c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6 ("storage-provisioner_kube-system(22d0437c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)"), skipping: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "22d0437c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox \"172f08e151ec2a7b12132bb65917b7d993cbba9978f4ff5d6f272fba132317d0\": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]"
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.549309    3010 remote_runtime.go:229] StopContainer "7058c1679128f30650a384e0ce3cfe31eff7fb2fbcd144b20fd26e1c94a1d61b" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.550191    3010 kuberuntime_container.go:604] Container "docker://7058c1679128f30650a384e0ce3cfe31eff7fb2fbcd144b20fd26e1c94a1d61b" termination failed with gracePeriod 30: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.549603    3010 remote_runtime.go:229] StopContainer "0837dc4d55ea00fe3367fce3b94e5a1baf5a2ed7f1affe4f315312bf94c68a21" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.554796    3010 kuberuntime_container.go:604] Container "docker://0837dc4d55ea00fe3367fce3b94e5a1baf5a2ed7f1affe4f315312bf94c68a21" termination failed with gracePeriod 30: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.556955    3010 remote_runtime.go:115] StopPodSandbox "69b05b274f31ee80f9e1e732e51d2a1859c81a9deaa913e54dcfafe891340acc" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.561291    3010 remote_runtime.go:115] StopPodSandbox "8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox "8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.561411    3010 kuberuntime_manager.go:595] killPodWithSyncResult failed: [failed to "KillContainer" for "kubedns" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillContainer" for "dnsmasq" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox \"8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec\": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]"
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:00.561442    3010 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod 23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6 ("kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)"), skipping: [failed to "KillContainer" for "kubedns" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillContainer" for "dnsmasq" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:00 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox \"8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec\": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]"
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.607038    3010 remote_runtime.go:229] StopContainer "7058c1679128f30650a384e0ce3cfe31eff7fb2fbcd144b20fd26e1c94a1d61b" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.607075    3010 kuberuntime_container.go:604] Container "docker://7058c1679128f30650a384e0ce3cfe31eff7fb2fbcd144b20fd26e1c94a1d61b" termination failed with gracePeriod 30: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.607162    3010 remote_runtime.go:229] StopContainer "0837dc4d55ea00fe3367fce3b94e5a1baf5a2ed7f1affe4f315312bf94c68a21" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.607177    3010 kuberuntime_container.go:604] Container "docker://0837dc4d55ea00fe3367fce3b94e5a1baf5a2ed7f1affe4f315312bf94c68a21" termination failed with gracePeriod 30: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.607527    3010 remote_runtime.go:115] StopPodSandbox "69b05b274f31ee80f9e1e732e51d2a1859c81a9deaa913e54dcfafe891340acc" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.607907    3010 remote_runtime.go:115] StopPodSandbox "8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox "8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.608521    3010 kuberuntime_manager.go:595] killPodWithSyncResult failed: [failed to "KillContainer" for "kubedns" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillContainer" for "dnsmasq" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox \"8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec\": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]"
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.608574    3010 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod 23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6 ("kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)"), skipping: [failed to "KillContainer" for "kubedns" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillContainer" for "dnsmasq" with KillContainerError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: , failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to get checkpoint for sandbox \"8536992fb81fc810a29b0fa41733a960b5ad422e0b5c8a2a206c1f8d165bc6ec\": key is not found, failed to get sandbox status: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?]"
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.683566    3010 remote_runtime.go:169] ListPodSandbox with filter &PodSandboxFilter{Id:,State:&PodSandboxStateValue{State:SANDBOX_READY,},LabelSelector:map[string]string{},} from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.683676    3010 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:192] ListPodSandbox failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:01 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:01.683710    3010 kubelet.go:1929] Failed cleaning pods: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Oct 23 01:45:05 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:05.299705    3010 proxier.go:964] Failed to delete kube-system/kube-dns:dns endpoint connections, error: error deleting conntrack entries for UDP peer {10.96.0.10, 172.17.0.3}, error: error looking for path of conntrack: exec: "conntrack": executable file not found in $PATH
Oct 23 01:45:09 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:09.791294    3010 remote_runtime.go:92] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube": Error response from daemon: transport is closing
Oct 23 01:45:09 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:09.791344    3010 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:54] CreatePodSandbox for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube": Error response from daemon: transport is closing
Oct 23 01:45:09 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:09.791356    3010 kuberuntime_manager.go:647] createPodSandbox for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube": Error response from daemon: transport is closing
Oct 23 01:45:09 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:09.791399    3010 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259 ("kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod \"kube-addon-manager-minikube\": Error response from daemon: transport is closing"
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.055640    3010 remote_runtime.go:92] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5": Error response from daemon: failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.endpoint: open : no such file or directory
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.055893    3010 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:54] CreatePodSandbox for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5": Error response from daemon: failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.endpoint: open : no such file or directory
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.056004    3010 kuberuntime_manager.go:647] createPodSandbox for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5": Error response from daemon: failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.endpoint: open : no such file or directory
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.056194    3010 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod 23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6 ("kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod \"kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5\": Error response from daemon: failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.endpoint: open : no such file or directory"
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770086    3010 remote_runtime.go:92] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/d3249fd7ea20fd2f6331f1cc78f3685b15fc63359992de039188960eafc893cd/start: EOF
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770123    3010 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:54] CreatePodSandbox for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/d3249fd7ea20fd2f6331f1cc78f3685b15fc63359992de039188960eafc893cd/start: EOF
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770133    3010 kuberuntime_manager.go:647] createPodSandbox for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/d3249fd7ea20fd2f6331f1cc78f3685b15fc63359992de039188960eafc893cd/start: EOF
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770174    3010 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod 23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6 ("kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5_kube-system(23825d5c-d333-11e8-b4fc-0800277656c6)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod \"kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-wk7v5\": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/d3249fd7ea20fd2f6331f1cc78f3685b15fc63359992de039188960eafc893cd/start: EOF"
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770502    3010 remote_runtime.go:92] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create a sandbox for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/create?name=k8s_POD_kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system_c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259_9: EOF
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770566    3010 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:54] CreatePodSandbox for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create a sandbox for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/create?name=k8s_POD_kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system_c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259_9: EOF
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770575    3010 kuberuntime_manager.go:647] createPodSandbox for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create a sandbox for pod "kube-addon-manager-minikube": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/create?name=k8s_POD_kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system_c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259_9: EOF
Oct 23 01:45:10 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:10.770602    3010 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259 ("kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system(c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create a sandbox for pod \"kube-addon-manager-minikube\": error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.31/containers/create?name=k8s_POD_kube-addon-manager-minikube_kube-system_c4c3188325a93a2d7fb1714e1abf1259_9: EOF"
Oct 23 01:45:23 minikube localkube[3010]: E1023 01:45:23.491216    3010 proxier.go:1701] Failed to delete stale service IP 10.96.0.10 connections, error: error deleting connection tracking state for UDP service IP: 10.96.0.10, error: error looking for path of conntrack: exec: "conntrack": executable file not found in $PATH
Oct 23 01:45:35 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:37382: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:35 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:37386: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:35 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:34088: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:35 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:37384: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:36 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:34112: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:36 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:37414: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:36 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:37416: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:36 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:37418: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:37 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:34120: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Oct 23 01:45:37 minikube localkube[21585]: http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.2:37422: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

It appears that the minikube had issues.  I am getting the same error when I start the minikube without proxy as well.

```
hyperkit version : hyperkit: v0.20180403-17-g3e954c
minikube version: v0.25.1
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.0", GitCommit:"0ed33881dc4355495f623c6f22e7dd0b7632b7c0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-28T15:20:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.11", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
```

> Ran kubectl -v9 cluster-info and below is the output.

```
I1023 00:11:12.639212   18611 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /Users/fna516/.kube/config
I1023 00:11:12.640094   18611 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /Users/fna516/.kube/config
I1023 00:11:12.641924   18611 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/0ed3388" 'https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s'
I1023 00:11:22.826784   18611 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s  in 10185 milliseconds
I1023 00:11:22.826808   18611 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1023 00:11:22.826900   18611 cached_discovery.go:111] skipped caching discovery info due to Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
I1023 00:11:22.827565   18611 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /Users/fna516/.kube/config
I1023 00:11:22.828233   18611 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/0ed3388" 'https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s'
I1023 00:11:32.943036   18611 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s  in 10115 milliseconds
I1023 00:11:32.943069   18611 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1023 00:11:32.943112   18611 cached_discovery.go:111] skipped caching discovery info due to Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
I1023 00:11:32.943161   18611 shortcut.go:89] Error loading discovery information: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
I1023 00:11:32.943340   18611 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/0ed3388" 'https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s'
I1023 00:11:43.397428   18611 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s  in 10454 milliseconds
I1023 00:11:43.397454   18611 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1023 00:11:43.397505   18611 cached_discovery.go:111] skipped caching discovery info due to Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
I1023 00:11:43.397619   18611 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/0ed3388" 'https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s'
I1023 00:11:53.510603   18611 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s  in 10113 milliseconds
I1023 00:11:53.510631   18611 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I1023 00:11:53.510677   18611 cached_discovery.go:111] skipped caching discovery info due to Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
I1023 00:11:53.510771   18611 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.12.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/0ed3388" 'https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s'
```

Comment: Can you run it like so to gather low-level debug info? `kubectl -v9 cluster-info` and share?

Comment: edited my post with the output

Comment: run it without proxy

Comment: I already mentioned in my question that I am getting the same error when I start the minikube without proxy as well.

Comment: It could be a lot of things that went wrong, I can suggest you to reinstall minikube and try again.   minikube stop; minikube delete; rm -r ~/.kube ~/.minikube